# Jquery/ Javascript For Loop being executed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have the following jquery code in my application and placed this in .js file and in HTML I have the following select.

```js
$(function() {
  for (i = 00; i < 24; i++) {
    $(".abcd").append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
  };
  var rating = ['A', 'A1', 'A2', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
  for (const item of rating) {
//        console.log(item);
    $(".bcde").append($('<option></option>').val(item).html(item));
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control abcd" multiple="multiple">
</select>
<select class="form-control bcde" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

I checked the console log for the item being printed and I see 
A
A1
A2
B
C
D
E
F
G
A
A1
A2
B
C
D
E
F
G
Similarly all the numbers from 1 to 23 are being repeated twice. Can you please help me with this issue.

Comment: Your loop variable `i` should be declared with `var` or `let`. That may not be the problem, but it should be done anyway.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Where do you see the numbers twice? Can you update the snippet in case I made wrong assumptions?

Comment: here in snippet its appending once only.where is the problem?

Comment: How and where did you load the `.js` file ? Did you maybe load it twice ?

Comment: thanks @Lapskaus. That was actually the reason for this issue. I removed the duplicate occurance and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if you only run it once. Here is a more elegant version

```js
const $opts = [...Array(24)].map(
  (_,i) => $("<option/>",{value:i,text:i}))
const $ratings = ['A', 'A1', 'A2', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'].map(
  (item) => $("<option/>",{value:item,text:item}))  
$(function() {
  $(".abcd").html($opts)
  $(".bcde").html($ratings);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control abcd" multiple="multiple">
</select>
<select class="form-control bcde" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your replies. The issue was because, I was calling the .js file twice in my code.